# Пропадает сессия при попытке внести изменения в базу данных

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, сессия

Есть проект, на котором развернута стандартная система регистрации/авторизации пользователей, основанная на механизме сессий. Авторизованный пользователь имеет возможность размещать на своей страничке объявления, статьи и т.д.

Для подобных изменений в базе данных используются *ajax*-запросы, для создания которых используется *jquery*, серверная платформа, как вы поняли, *ruby on rails*.

В каждом *ajax*-запросе передается *csrf*.

Когда пользователь заходит на сайт с браузера, с которого не заходил ранее, и пытается разместить статью или объявление, или внести любые другие изменения в базу данных, пропадает сессия - я имею ввиду что после нажатия на кнопку РАЗМЕСТИТЬ, на том месте, где должна быть опубликованная статья/объявление, появляется главная страничка, и далее, после перезагрузки, меня выбрасывает на главную страничку.

В то же время запросы из базы данных на получение данных проходят нормально, ошибка появляется только при попытке внести изменения.

И вот еще интересный момент: если пользователь повторно проходит авторизацию на сайте, то ошибка пропадает, т.е. пользователь свободно имеет возможность вносить изменения в базу, без каких-либо проблем.

В чем может быть причина такого поведения? Что делать? Куда бежать? В каком направлении смотреть?

Comment: Что за gem используется для раздачи прав доступа? И покажите экшн контроллера, при выполнени которого, перебрасывает на главную страницу.

Comment: Для раздачи прав доступа никакой gem не использовался, только before_filter используется, в котором проверяется session

Comment: Тогда нужен контроллер, в котором происходит добавление.

Comment: def save_field
# бла-бла-бла, юзаем params, сохраняем модели, ну или не сохраняем - в зависимости от параметров. session вообще не трогаем
render :partial => "/lk/article"
end

Comment: в контроллере есть before_filter :logged_in
logged_in - частные метод (private)

private
def logged_in
if session бла-бла-бла
redirect_to страница_логина
end
end